# This Folder Does Not Belong to You

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-files, mount

I followed [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1449168) guide to encrypt my home folder and now I cannot access my external hard drive. As this guide instructs, I created a temporary user with encrypted home and migrated all my files to that user. I also made sure that the new user belongs to the same groups as my old user. After some time I deleted the old user. Everything else aside from this mounting problem seems to be working fine.

Screenshot of the problem:
[image: This Folder Does Not Belong to You. You don't have permission to view this folder.]

Comment: Try opening files as administrator

Comment: Thanks. This works. Nevertheless, it's a temporary solution. I am actually using Deja Dup backup software with the backup destination in this external hard drive.

Comment: Change the permissions of the folder to give the normal user full access

Comment: Thanks again. I had to change the ownership of /media/magnus folder. It was owned by root:root. Now everything works. You may create an answer so that I can accept it. :)

Comment: I will upvote this post in about 12hrs because I have ran out of votes today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Pantheon files as an administrator. Then change the owner of the `/media/magnus` folder to the correct user. Now your user should have full access to mounted media.

Comment: I didn't need to change the owner of my home directory but the owner of the /media/magnus directory.

Comment: Did you change the permissions?

Comment: No. I only needed to change ownership. Also, I edited the answer, so you don't have to do it yourself. It's not peer reviewed yet.

Comment: I have accepted it.Now I have too imrpove the formatting of it

Comment: OK. Improved  formatting

Comment: It would be VERY helpful to explain HOW to change the file owner.  Not just say "change the file owner".

Comment: ```man chown``` is your friend